# Displaying edited images in asp.net application from dreamweaver

Tags: asp.net, dreamweaver, photoshop

I created an image using photoshop. I then saved it as an html file and then exported it to dreamweaver. I then tried to create a link based on the slices I created using photoshop. This worked. My problem is that, when I go to save the image whilst in dreamweaver, it always wants to save it as an html file. I want to save the image as a jpeg so I can then use it in my asp.net application. When I try to save the image I edited in dreamweaver as a jpeg file, when I run my asp.net page, the image does not display at all.

Basically, I have created an image in photoshop, added some text to it, then saved it as an html file. I now just want to create links in certain parts of my image where the text is using dreamweaver, then display that image in my asp.net website. Can someone help please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Images don't quite work that way.

When you export an image from Photoshop to Dreamweaver, it should be creating slices of the image and then embedding them in divs or tables as background images.  The images themselves should be saving in whichever folder you designated to hold images when you created the site definition.

What you can do is isolate the slice with the text and bring that one image to the foreground (use a regular img tag) and then use the Image Map tool in the Properties bar to create the clickable areas.

The end result is still image files and HTML code but you can import that to any page type.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver is not an image editing tool, which is why you can not save an image from it. Dreamweaver is a Website/webpage editing tool, which is why there is Fireworks which was the Image editing companion to Dreamweaver before Adobe bought out Macromedia.

An html page, and by extension asp.net (.aspx) pages are not images and should not be treated as such. They are a collection of the mark-up (html), presentation/style(CSS), images, and client side functionality (javascript). You need to have a good understanding of each of these elements and their interaction.

Photoshop and Dreamweaver are a dangerous combination for someone just getting into web development as you get the illusion of achieving a lot quickly while never getting an understanding of the basic mechanics of how a web page works.

It sounds like you need to go back to basics. Google some basic HTML tutorials on **Hand Coding** some pages.

Rant over